# How can I make position sticky work here

Tags: html, css, sticky

In this website, I would like the navigation bar to stick to the top of the page when scrolling down. I don't know why my website is allowing this to happen (I have position: sticky, top: 0 and overflow is not set to anything).

If anyone is willing to help, please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the html file and the css file:

```css
{-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}

body {
 margin: 0%;
 font-family: Arial;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 background: linear-gradient(#e6e6e6, white);
}

.header {
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 font-size: 187%;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 1.5%;
 background-color: white;
 color: grey;
 z-index: 2;
}

.card {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.card p {
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.card p:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.card a {
 float: left;
 color: grey;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 0.7%;
 padding-bottom: 0.7%;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.card a:hover {
 color: #3399ff;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.navigation {
 list-style-type: none;
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1%;
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover:not(.active), .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 min-width: 1%;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 color: grey;
 padding: 10%;
 width: 80%;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: white;
}

.active {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}

.active:hover {
 background-color: #80bfff;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.about a {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
}

br.clearLeft {
   clear: left;        
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

<title>Testing</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class = "header";>Website</div>

<div class = "navigation";>
 <li><a class = "active" href = "#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li class = "dropdown">
  <a class = "dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
  <div class = "dropdown-content">
   <a href = "#link1">Link 1</a>
   <a href = "#link2">Link 2</a>
   <a href = "#link3">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class = "about";><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 <br class="clearLeft" />
</div>


<div class = "card";>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

`float: left` property of `.card > p` let their parent `.card` cannot wrap them, and because of this, the height of `.card` is not expanded, so neither does the height of `body`, the effect of sticky property has no room to show.

```css
{-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
 
body {
 margin: 0%;
 font-family: Arial;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 background: linear-gradient(#e6e6e6, white);
    // Add--------
        height: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header {
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 font-size: 187%;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 1.5%;
 background-color: white;
 color: grey;
 z-index: 2;
}

.card {
    overflow: hidden;     <-- to wrap the p elements.
 position: relative;
 margin-right: 2%;
 margin-left: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.card p {
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.card p:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.card a {
 float: left;
 color: grey;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 1%;
 padding-right: 1%;
 padding-top: 0.7%;
 padding-bottom: 0.7%;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.card a:hover {
 color: #3399ff;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 1%;
 color: grey;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

li a:hover:not(.active), .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
 min-width: 1%;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 color: grey;
 padding: 10%;
 width: 80%;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: white;
}

.active {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}

.active:hover {
 background-color: #80bfff;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.about a {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
}

br.clearLeft {
   clear: left;        
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">

<title>Testing</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class = "header";>Website</div>

<div class = "navigation";>
 <li><a class = "active" href = "#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li class = "dropdown">
  <a class = "dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
  <div class = "dropdown-content">
   <a href = "#link1">Link 1</a>
   <a href = "#link2">Link 2</a>
   <a href = "#link3">Link 3</a>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class = "about";><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 <br class="clearLeft" />
</div>


<div class = "card";>
 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>

 <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei te semper legimus dissentiunt, pro mollis intellegam et. Pri ad nullam essent. An praesent instructior vel. Falli mediocrem quo at, tollit ornatus ut eos. Pro ea munere commune, ex qui possit prompta elaboraret, ea pro audiam disputando. Per suas gubergren ne.
  Primis civibus per te. Per no ignota imperdiet. Duo no nemore eripuit ponderum, cum at delectus disputando, dicant veniam perfecto vix id. Cum eu euripidis omittantur efficiantur, at invenire disputationi eos. Meis abhorreant mea te, at vidisse mnesarchum qui. Vis feugait electram consequuntur an.
  Nec an dicit mundi sententiae, te sea possim appetere contentiones. Eu nec facete neglegentur, nec te quaestio repudiandae. Duo clita interesset ut, nulla detracto scriptorem sit ex, phaedrum argumentum no eum. Ut alia vide mazim eam, dicunt pericula principes duo no, cu ius tollit delectus. In mea habeo docendi theophrastus, no vis pertinax gloriatur. Ad ocurreret consulatu persequeris quo, his amet bonorum ad, ea eos oblique nominati assentior. Solet affert legimus vel id, eu his vide quas utinam, partem scripserit his te.
  Per ne agam labore aliquam. Tota sententiae cum eu. Nulla malorum maluisset no per. Te eos wisi facer probatus, mazim possit adversarium ex eum, ex vel mollis eloquentiam.
  Quot quaeque alterum mei ut, ex eum laboramus aliquando. Alienum dolores dissentias eum ea, dicta sonet scribentur mel et. At sea congue dignissim, labore alienum ne eum. Tantas offendit ad pri, has feugait erroribus ea, ea vim tibique vulputate. Pro minimum detraxit recteque cu, dico nullam fastidii sit id, sonet disputationi ne nam.
  <br />
  <br />
  <a href = "#link";>Link</a>
 </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using overflow:hidden on .card, since it cuts off the shadows around the card

Comment: never mind I just put the card class within another class that only had overflow:hidden.